# Does encrypted session key need to be authenticated?

Tags: encryption, authentication

I have the following working test...

```
public void Test1()
{
    var symmetricEncryption = new SymmetricEncryption();
    var asymmetricEncrption = new AsymmetricEncryption();

    var pipeline = new Pipeline(symmetricEncryption, asymmetricEncrption);

    var keyPair = asymmetricEncrption.NewKey();

    var secretMessage = "Hello World!";

    var encryptedPackage = pipeline.Encrypt(keyPair, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretMessage));

    var decryptedMessage = pipeline.Decrypt(keyPair, encryptedPackage);

    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedMessage);

    Assert.Equal(secretMessage, message);
}
```

Pipeline looks like this...

```
public class Pipeline
{
    readonly ISymmetricEncryption symmetricEncryption;
    readonly IAsymmetricEncryption asymmetricEncryption;

    public Pipeline(ISymmetricEncryption symmetricEncryption, IAsymmetricEncryption asymmetricEncryption)
    {
        this.symmetricEncryption = symmetricEncryption;
        this.asymmetricEncryption = asymmetricEncryption;
    }

    public byte [] Encrypt(string publicKey, byte [] messageToEncrypt)
    {
        var sessionKey = symmetricEncryption.NewKey();

        var encryptedBytes = symmetricEncryption.Encrypt(sessionKey, messageToEncrypt);

        var encryptedKeyBytes = asymmetricEncryption.Encrypt(publicKey, sessionKey);

        var allBytes = WriteBytes(encryptedBytes, encryptedKeyBytes);

        return allBytes;
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(string privateKey, byte [] encryptedPackage)
    {
        var (encryptedKey, encryptedMessage) = ReadBytes(encryptedPackage);

        var sessionKey = asymmetricEncryption.Decrypt(privateKey, encryptedKey);

        var decryptedMessage = symmetricEncryption.Decrypt(sessionKey, encryptedMessage);

        return decryptedMessage;
    }

    static byte[] WriteBytes(byte[] encryptedBytes, byte[] encryptedKeyBytes)
    {
        using var stream = new MemoryStream();

        stream.Write(encryptedBytes);

        stream.Write(encryptedKeyBytes);

        return stream.ToArray();
    }

    static (byte[] key, byte[] message) ReadBytes(byte[] encryptedMessage)
    {
        const int encryptedSessionKeyLength = 256;

        var encryptedMessageStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedMessage);

        using var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(encryptedMessageStream);

        var encryptedMessage0 = binaryReader.ReadBytes(encryptedMessage.Length - encryptedSessionKeyLength);

        var encryptedSessionKey = binaryReader.ReadBytes(encryptedSessionKeyLength);

        return (encryptedSessionKey, encryptedMessage0);
    }
}
```

For the symmetric encryption I have used AESGCM.cs from [here](https://gist.github.com/jbtule/4336842), so I think I have authentication in effect for the message.

Asymmetric also uses Bouncy Castle and looks like this...

```
public byte[] Encrypt(string keyString, byte[] message)
{
    using var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

    var key = ParseKey(keyString);

    csp.ImportParameters(key);

    var bytesCypherText = csp.Encrypt(message, false);

    return bytesCypherText;
}

public byte[] Decrypt(string keyString, byte[] cypherText)
{
    using var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

    var key = ParseKey(keyString);

    csp.ImportParameters(key);

    var plainBytes = csp.Decrypt(cypherText, false);

    return plainBytes;
}
```

I've got some funny looking characters so this appears to be doing something. The question is... does the encrypted session key need to be authenticated too or does it not matter if it's tampered with?

Comment: Are you doing this because you'd like to understand cryptography more? Or are you doing this because some app you intend to use needs to use cryptography?

Comment: An app that uses Cryptography.

Comment: Then I would **highly recommend** getting a security assessment for your code before it goes into production. Crypto is easy to get wrong, and it's not immediately obvious if it is wrong. And if it goes wrong, it's usually really bad.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the advice. Do you see any problems with the code? What about the answer to thew question.

Comment: I can't review crypto code within 5 minutes and give you any assessment as to how suitable it is for production. Not in good conscience at least.

Comment: Fair enough. How much does a code review cost? Besides that, is encrypting a session key sufficiently secure?

Comment: That depends highly on the company, the scope of the assessment, etc. I suggest talking to your project leader about it, if this is something that the company should do or not.

Comment: Yes, although there's not much point in getting a code review if I don't have any code in the first place.

Comment: @MechMK1 Well they've agreed to shelve it for now. Is it fair to say that auditing security code is a normal part of doing security?

Comment: In a perfect world, code would be audited regularly and the final product would be blackbox tested extensively. Sadly, those things cost money, so audits are rarer than they should be.